# Journey builder email send activity exclusion script issue

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder, exclusion-script

I am trying to use an exclusion script in an email send activity to inject data to a data extension. I have no intention of sending the email.

I have tried with both upsertDE() (the email send version of the function) and upsertData() (the script activity and landing page version of the function).

It works 100% of the time when running the script in an email send, script activity or landing page, but does not seem to work as an exclusion script within journey builder.

Exclusion script:
`TreatAsContent(ContentBlockByKey("test_script"))==1`

Content Block with Key 'test_script':

```
%%[ 
Var @subkey, @content, @name, @result
Set @subkey = _subscriberkey
Set @name = "John"
Set @content = "Hello World"
Set @result = 1
UpsertDE(
"test_script_de"
,1
,"subscriberkey",@subkey 
,"name", @name
,"content",@content
) 
]%% 
%%=v(@result)=%%
```

Comment: That’s not really what exclusion scripts are used for. They shouldn’t ever be used to write data, if even possible. What are you trying to accomplish? Upserting rows to a DE? Why not use the Update Contact activity in JB?

Comment: I realise it's not what they are intended for, but we would find it very useful to be able to trigger scripts with journey builder, without having to send an email. In this use case update contact activity won't work as we want to render dynamic content and enter it into a separate data extension.

Comment: If JB is a must. I would use JB to add the rows to a DE (update contact activity), and an automation studio script activity to process the rows in that DE. By using the product in unintended ways, you are setting yourself up for unintended consequences.

Comment: You can also create a custom JB activity (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/creating-activities.htm). It isn't easy to do, but gives you many options and features that are not native to JB.

Comment: The reason we state that it is not what those are used for is because any 'hack' in SFMC is an 'at your own risk' process. Meaning the risk of failure is increased and there is no support available by SFMC on your process. This is far from an optimum approach for any significant or important campaign in SFMC.

Comment: @Gortonington, we were going to explore developing a custom JB activity if we can't make it work using native SFMC features. However when I saw that it is possible to run scripts within journey builder already, I was hoping we wouldn't have to!

Comment: @Tyler, Thanks for the suggestion but this will not work for our use case. We are already running similar scripts in automation studio for journeys that are triggered on a recurring schedule and it works great, but it does not work in journeys that are triggered by Salesforce events as we need the script to render the content as close to real-time as possible. We realise it's not how the tool is intended and SFMC support will not help if something goes wrong. However if we can run scripts as part of a journey builder flow, it would make SFMC significantly more powerful for us.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a little less creativity - the "hacky" approach does have its downsides as stated.

Another suggestion:

You *can* use an Update Contact Event to write into a separate Data Extension.

Your separate DE needs to have the following configuration:

- Sendable
- A field with the exact name of "SubscriberKey"
- Subscriber Relationship on SubscriberKey = Subscriber Key
- other fields to your liking

Configure the activity in such a fashion that all the "other" fields are populated, but simply ignore the SubscriberKey field in the activity. It will auto-populate in this setup.  This will help you track your dynamic journey setup in many cases.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Update contact activity will actually upsert.

Comment: ah sorry, confused it. in that case, there is nothing that wouldn't work. I'll edit the answer.